# Prerequistes for learning how to code a facebook application

Tags: facebook

I am facing a really tough time doing this. I haven't done much on web development before this. I know HTML and dats it. What else do I need to learn in order to start coding a good facebook app (specifically scripting languages like JS, PHP, MySQL etc). I have already created a test application using a web hosting site. Time is of the essence here.

Comment: What kind of application is it? What does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would pick up [Head First Servlets and JSP](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsvlt/) or [Head First PHP & MySQL](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfphp/). They will be your best friends in the process of writing PHP or JSP.  Then of course you should learn what's in the Facebook API and how to use it.

You mentioned that time is off the essence, but I simply can't think of a reasonable way by which you can learn PHP or JSP without putting in the grunt work (which takes time).  You should definitely do some reading unless you want to make an app that's hacker's paradise.

If you're already familiar with Java, then JSP will feel more natural and probably easier/faster to learn.

P.S. Sorry for the multiple edits... I felt like my wording was a bit off.

Comment: And I'd add: learn how to code a regular web app, and then build a Facebook app. Otherwise it's going to be an uphill struggle to debug. If time is of the essence, then you should probably hire someone who does know how to do it.